# How to get all facebook app request for a user of my apps without storing them

Tags: facebook, apprequests

We are building a apps and we want to clear all the apps request for our user when he log into our apps.

I know we could store the request when we send them and clear them when the user log to the apps. 
But is there anyway to get all the apps request from FB (through fb api or fql) instead of storing them in our apps.

Comment: App requests he *received or *sent*?

Comment: received, I founded a request in the graph api that might do the trick : https://graph.facebook.com/[user-fb-id]/apprequests and SELECT recipient_uid, request_id, app_id FROM apprequest WHERE recipient_uid = me() AND app_id = [app_id]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Facebook apprequests](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7192269/problem-with-facebook-apprequests)